# Populate a text box using a selected value in a dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, php

I have this two tables in my database

1 - tbl_category

2 - tbl_shelf_place

(I want to achieve this kind of output where the selected category_name from the drop-down (book_category) with a value of category_id will show the shelf_code in a textbox instead of a DROPDOWN, based on the equivalent shelf_id).

```
  --------------------------           -------------------------
         tlb_category                      tbl_shelf_place
 ---------------------------         -------------------------
 category_id | category_name              shelf_id| shelf_code
 ---------------------------           -------------------------
           1 | General Works                 1    | General Works Shelf
           2 | History                       2    | History Shelf
```

Below is my current code for the dependent dropdown.

My dropdown code in HTML

```
<select id="book_category" name="book_category" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-danger" onChange="getState(this.value);" required>
  <option disabled selected value=""> Choose Category
  </option>
  <?php
$query = "SELECT category_id , category_name FROM tbl_category";
$stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($category_id , $category_name);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$getcategoryID = $category_id;
$getcategoryname = $category_name;
echo "<option value='{$getcategoryID}'>{$getcategoryname}</option>";
}
?>
    </select>
<select id="book_shelf" name="book_shelf" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-danger" required>
  <option disabled selected value="">
  </option>
</select>
```

My script code

```
<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dropdownrequest.php",
    data:'category_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#book_shelf").html(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

dropdownrequest.php

```
<?php
include_once ("../database/dbconnect.php");

if(!empty($_POST["category_id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_shelf_place WHERE shelf_id = '" . $_POST["category_id"] . "'";
    $results = $mysqlconnection->query($query);
?>

<?php
    foreach($results as $shelf) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $shelf["shelf_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $shelf["shelf_code"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: in that way you get ur output in select Tag.

Comment: yes , but instead of showing the output in a select tag i want it to be in a textbox.

Comment: but in ur code book_shelf is made in select Tag????

Comment: yes , i tried to change it into an input tag but it doesn't show the shelf_code when i select a category from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
<select id="book_category" name="book_category" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn btn-danger" onChange="getState(this.value);" required>
  <option disabled selected value=""> Choose Category
  </option>
  <?php
$query = "SELECT category_id , category_name FROM tbl_category";
$stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($category_id , $category_name);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
$getcategoryID = $category_id;
$getcategoryname = $category_name;
echo "<option value='{$getcategoryID}'>{$getcategoryname}</option>";
}
?>
    </select>
<textarea id="book_shelf" name="book_shelf"></textarea>
```

In your JS.

```
<script>
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dropdownrequest.php",
    data:'category_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#book_shelf").val(data);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

In you PHP code.

```
<?php
include_once ("../database/dbconnect.php");

if(!empty($_POST["category_id"])) {
    $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_shelf_place WHERE shelf_id = '" . $_POST["category_id"] . "'";
    $results = $mysqlconnection->query($query);
    $shelf_text = '';
    foreach($results as $shelf) {
     $shelf_text .= $shelf["shelf_id"]." - ".$shelf["shelf_code"];
     }
    echo $shelf_text;
    exit;
}
?>
```

Hope this will give you and Idea. I haven't tested this code so please pardon if there is any syntax error. Also tweak the code in PHP file so you can show the shelf_code and shelf_id as per your requirements.

Comment: Well it works in a textarea but if i change it into an input tag it doen't show the shelf_code anymore , thats so weird

Comment: Show me your input tag please?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="book_shelf" name="book_shelf" required  > its a normal input tag but it doesn't show the shelf_code idk why

Comment: <textarea id="book_shelf" class="form-control text-center"  name="book_shelf"></textarea> this the textarea tag

Comment: In you ajax success alert data. alert(data). What response are you getting?

Comment: Im getting the equivalent shelf_code but its not showing in my input tag

Comment: Can you please print the data here?

Comment: Also in your js try like this. $("body input#book_shelf").val(data);

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, one way to achieve this

**PHP**

```
<?php
 include_once ("../database/dbconnect.php");

 if(!empty($_POST["category_id"])) {
     $query ="SELECT * FROM tbl_shelf_place WHERE shelf_id = '" . 
     $_POST["category_id"] . "'";
     $results = $mysqlconnection->query($query);
     foreach($results as $shelf){
       echo $shelf["shelf_code"];
     }     
 }
?>
```

No need to return `option` now. Just read the data returned and add it to your `textbox` element in HTML

**HTML**

```
<select id="book_category" name="book_category" class="selectpicker" data- 
 style="btn btn-danger" onChange="getState(this.value);" required>
   <option disabled selected value=""> Choose Category</option>
  <?php
      $query = "SELECT category_id , category_name FROM tbl_category";
      $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($category_id , $category_name);
      while($stmt->fetch())
      {
         $getcategoryID = $category_id;
         $getcategoryname = $category_name;
         echo "<option value='{$getcategoryID}'>{$getcategoryname} 
         </option>";
     }
   ?>
   </select>
   // Add HTML Textbox here
   <input type="text" id="book_shelf">
```

Rest of the code should be same.